# React Navigation v5 use custom header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to have a custom header if I set the header to be off in React-Navigation V5?

I tried to, but the `headerLeft` and `headerRight` seems to do nothing, for example, I have the following:

```
<Stack.Screen
  component={UploadStack}
  name="UploadStack"
  options={{ headerShown: false }}
/>
```

and then in my `UploadStack`, I have

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="TrackUploadSelectionScreen">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="AddToPlaylistScreen"
        component={AddToPlaylistScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="TrackUploadSelectionScreen"
        component={TrackUploadSelectionScreen}
        options={{
          title: t('general.selectToUpload'),
          headerLeft: () =>
            Platform.select({
              ios: () => (
                <NavigationHeader.TextButton
                  label={t('general.cancel')}
                  onPress={navigation.goBack()}
                />
              ),
              android: () => (
                <NavigationHeader.IconButton
                  iconName="times"
                  label={t('general.cancel')}
                  onPress={navigation.goBack()}
                />
              )
            })
        }}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

but it isn't creating anything

Answer (score 8):

The method I found that worked was adding a function that renders react elements to the header attribute on the `Stack.Navigator` component. This would allow it to appear for every `Stack.Screen` child element.

Example as shown,

```js
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Page1"
  screenOptions={{header: NavHeader}}
>
     <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
     <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

The NavHeader component can be simple react element. In this example you would simply have it as a function.

```js
function NavHeader() {
    return <View>...</View>;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set `headerShown` to `false` everything you set for the `headerLeft`, `headerRight` and `header` properties is not going to be shown. So remove that line if you do want to set any of these properties.

Additionally if you want to have a custom header, instead of the default bar you can simple set the `header` property. Here is an example of a custom header where the bar is removed, but 2 very simple buttons are placed on the left and the right using flexbox.

```
// ...
<Stack.Screen
  options={{
    header: () => (
      <View
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          height: 50,
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ padding: 10 }}
          onPress={() => {
            alert('Left');
          }}>
          <Text>Left</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ padding: 10 }}
          onPress={() => {
            alert('Right');
          }}>
          <Text>Right</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    ),
  }}
  // Other props...
/>
// ...
```

You can adjust the styling and content to fit your needs.

Comment: Yeah but I want to disable the header the navigation comes with so I have to do the headerShown: false, right?

Comment: No, like I mentioned if you set headerShown to false you can't set a custom header, so you only set that if you don't want to show anything at all. If you want to have a custom header you provide one using the `header` prop to override the default one like I showed in the example.